# Confused on what license to choose

Tags: open-source, licensing

I have worked with my friend on a project and made a website. This is the website: [TOFSIS](http://tofsis.com)

It's more or less like an Educational CMS. Now the thing is, it's in its initial stage. We still have to prepare more modules for the site as instructed by the college.

So, my partner and I thought of making it open sourced so that people in college can build on it. We want to choose from a pool of eligible developers who are really interested and give the codes only to them under certain conditions so that they can prepare a particular module for the site or fix the existing bugs. And for things like GPA calculator, attendance calculator, you don't need the codes for the site.

I read completely about licenses and I don't think we can choose open source license as yet because we are not giving out the codes now. But what about Creative Commons? Just adding a CC badge like SO.

I see that on SO footer there is a CC stamp. SO is not open sourced to my knowledge. But I also heard CC is not meant for softwares or codes. So when does a developer use CC license? And is it fair in my case to use a GPL without giving out the code now but put some more additional custom conditions?

What should I do in my case? I want to put up a license. I don't want anyone to commercialise and I want people to share back things too.

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [AGPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affero_General_Public_License) is possibly the best license choice if you want to make the source code open for people to improve, but also want to force people to share back their improvements.

It doesn't explicitly prevent commercialisation, but anyone who makes a commercial derivative work would have to share all their changes under the AGPL. In practice, this means that a commercial entity would have to find some other way of creating value, e.g. providing value-added services.

**Note**: The [Open Source Definition](http://opensource.org/docs/osd), require that a license has *"No Discrimination Against Fields Of Endeavour"*. This means that you can't go adding clauses that prohibit commercial use if you want to be classified as open source. You have to let businesses use open source code fairly on the same terms, just like everyone else.

Answer (score 1):

Before I answer, first a question: why not make the code widely available? Since you appear to have no intention of commercializing it, why go through the hassle of using a non-OSS licence (which will spark discussions with your contributors).

Anyway, a good licence could be the [Microsoft Reference Source Licence](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/referencesourcelicensing.aspx), which will allow viewing rights, but not modification / redistribution. You can make a separate agreement to allow specific people to contribute, ask a lawyer since this goes into contract-law territory (you need permission from them to re-license their code).

Answer (score 1):

> But I also heard CC is not meant for softwares or codes. So when does a developer use CC license?

A software developer ***should never*** use a CC license for a software program.

Creative Common licenses are fitting for works like images, photos, music, video or the text of documents.

They are less fitting for software because a software program has two forms: object code and source code. The CC licenses do not work well with these two forms. E.g you can edit a photo or a music quite well, that does not work well with software if you don't have the source-code.

CC on stackoverflow btw. is used for the content. So you can edit my answer now and improve it ;)